# Different liquid restrictions in China and Philippines

Tags: airports, china, airport-security, philippines

Recently I flew from London (UK) to Manila (Philippines) with a stop in Beijing (China). On my way back I had a couple of bottles (no more than 100ml), but neither in Manila nor Beijing (I went out to visit the city and I passed the security scans on my way back to the gate), I was asked to take out the liquids and put them on a plastic bag (The only thing it was one pack of candies they thought it was a lighter).

My question is, are there different restriction or even none at all about liquids in those countries?

Comment: I think covering all Asia in one question is too broad, each country has different rules.

Comment: I was asking broad because it happened to me in 2 different countries. I can edit if you want

Comment: Its not what I want, it is the site's rules. Asking a question that is too broad is not useful. But if you asked a question about a specific country it will useful to you and to many other who will face the same problem. I suggest you ask about China for example in this question and start another question about the Philippines. This way both questions will be useful to many people :)

Comment: @HaLaBi I changed the title. Is it better now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Offically, yes the liquid rules are in effect, the Manila International Airport Authority has a Liquids, Aerosols and Gels page but it's a mirror on a numeric IP address so I can't link it. This is the [Main Site](http://www.miaa.gov.ph), click FAQ from there. From that page:

> **What is the best advice to get me through security as smoothly as possible?**
>
> Pack all liquids into checked-in luggage. This will ensure a smooth journey through passenger security screening areas. If it is necessary for you to have liquids and gels in your carry-on luggage, Click here to view our policy in the carriage of liquids and gels.

The link there goes to their liquids/gels page which has the same restrictions as everywhere else.

Having said that I live in Manila and have never been asked to remove liquids or laptops, or anything like that. **But** if you change planes on route in a different country you're very likely to be hit with the liquid restrictions there. And things change, so I wouldn't rely on doing that.

I can't find anything on the [Beijing Airport](http://en.bcia.com.cn/) site talking about it but here's Hong Kong's [leaflet](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/img/passenger/liquid_security_20070321.gif).

The International Civil Aviation Organization has a [FAQ](http://www.icao.int/Security/Documents/Aviation%20Security%20FAQs/AVSEC_FAQs_2012-08-28.pdf) which says:

> **Why do security controls vary from airport to airport?**
>
> ICAO sets minimum standards to be met by Member States in all ﬁ elds of international civil aviation, including aviation security.
> States must comply with these baseline standards, but they may also add measures according to national requirements based
> on risk assessments. As a result, national and regional variations in the type of security controls can emerge.

**Short answer**: Technically no difference in restrictions in Asia, but enforcement varies.

Comment: So, in short they just apply the law in a different way. I thought they were starting to remove that rule in Asia.

Comment: I've heard speculation that the rule may change globally with new explosives detecting tech. I think countries play it safe by stating that it's the rule, but then just don't bother to enforce it when they can get away with it. I know Manila airport is undergoing a long overhaul / revamp, maybe they'll redo security then and start enforcing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are Airport guidelines that I found in the internet regarding what to bring and what not to bring when checking-in.

[Customs and Airport Guidelines](http://www.phitex.ph/customs-and-airport-guidelines/)

NEW RULES FOR TAKING LIQUIDS, AEROSOLS AND GELS THROUGH SECURITY ONTO INTERNATIONAL AND DOMESTIC FLIGHTS

Are your liquids, aerosols and gels 100ml or less?

Liquids, aerosols and gels include items such as drinks, creams, perfumes, sprays, gels, toothpaste, lipstick, lip balm and similar substances

[image: lists of items allowed and items that are not allow]